# Поиск удвоенных нечетных чисел среди компонент

Tags: python

Дан файл, компоненты которого являются целыми числами. Найти
удвоенные нечетные числа среди компонент. Я прописал следующий код:

```
myList = [input()]
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as file1:
  f1 = file1.writelines(myList)
newList = open('file1.txt', 'r').read().split()
print(newList)
myInt = 2
num = [x / myInt for x in newList]
print(num[i])
for i in range(num):
  if i%2 == 0:
    n = num[i]
    i+1
print(n)
```

Но у меня выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
----> 7 num = [x / myInt for x in newList]
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `int(x)`, наверно.

Comment: В заголовке должно быть краткое описание проблемы, а не сочинение на тему "что я делал прошлым летом"

Answer (score 1):

```
num = [x / myInt for x in newList]
```

когда вы разбили считанную строку из файла на числа, то получили опять таки строки
их надо перевести в числа, сами по себе они не не переведутся

```
num = [int(x) / myInt for x in newList]
```

или предварительно

```
newList = list(map(int, open('file1.txt', 'r').read().split()))
```

ну и по самой задаче - что вы хотите достигнуть делив 2 на число, например 2 на 11 - какое удвоение вы так определите?

удвоенное нечетное число (если я правильно) - выглядит так

```
if i % 2 == 0 and (i // 2) % 2 == 1
```

ну или

```
if i % 4 == 2
```